# How do I Install WinRT Side loading Build or Package

Tags: windows-runtime, sideloading

I have created build WinRT log back before 2 Months, now I am going to install side loading.
[Sideloadingstep(Clickme)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2012/11/05/how-do-i-deploy-a-windows-8-app-to-another-device-for-testing.aspx)
and getting error like

```
Found bundle: C:\Users\jitendra.jadav\Downloads\iLitInstructor_3_1_5\iLitInstructor\iLitInstructor_3.1.5.314_Debug_Test\
iLitInstructor_3.1.5.314_x64_arm_Debug.appxbundle
Found certificate: C:\Users\jitendra.jadav\Downloads\iLitInstructor_3_1_5\iLitInstructor\iLitInstructor_3.1.5.314_Debug_
Test\iLitInstructor_3.1.5.314_x64_arm_Debug.cer
Error: The developer certificate "C:\Users\jitendra.jadav\Downloads\iLitInstructor_3_1_5\iLitInstructor\iLitInstructor_3
.1.5.314_Debug_Test\iLitInstructor_3.1.5.314_x64_arm_Debug.cer" has expired. One possible cause is the system clock isn'
t set to the correct date and time. If the system settings are correct, contact the app owner to re-create a package or
bundle with a valid certificate.
Press Enter to continue...:
```

**Note : The System Date is Correct..**

my scenario is different if it is in development then that is fine but we have different environment like QA, Staging and Prod so...App is already on Staging and this developer license is not valid for 1 year but it is only for 1 month so assume app is in staging environment how would I install this app into my device.? I don't have a choice to generate new certificate and make new build... does is there any way to make this happen..? if yes then how...note : without making new build.
How to solve this problem..

Thank you,
~Jitendra.

Comment: Have you checked: "One possible cause is the system clock isn't set to the correct date and time. If the system settings are correct, contact the app owner to re-create a package or bundle with a valid certificate."?

Comment: Yes, I checked it and it is correct..

Comment: Have you verified that the certificate in the bundle is correct? And if not may I advise you "contact the app owner to re-create a package or bundle with a valid certificate"

Comment: yes, earlier it was working fine and now it is giving me error like  I mention.

Comment: by the way I am developer so all the stuff I am doing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the temporary certificate generated by Visual Studio for the app has expired; it only has 1 year validity from the day the project was created.

Since you are the developer, you can easily check that from within Visual Studio. Double-click on the `Package.appxmanifest` file to open the designer and click on the *Packaging* tab. Click on the *Choose Certificate...* button there and check the *Expiration Date*:

[image: Certificate Expiration Date]

If it did already expire, you will need to create a new temporary certificate. Click on the *Configure Certificate...* button and select *Create Test Certificate* from the dropdown. You can just confirm the default values provided to generate a new certificate.

Now rebuild the project, recreate the package and try sidaloding it again on the test machine.

Comment: Thank Damir, but my scenario is different if it is in development then that is fine but we have different environment like QA, Staging and Prod so...App is already on Staging and this developer license is not valid for 1 year but it is only for 1 month so assume app is in staging environment how would I install this app into my device.? I don't have a choice to generate new certificate and make new build... does is there any way to make this happen..? if yes then how...note : without making new build.

Comment: @JitendraJadav Well, you should only use Visual Studio's test certificate for testing. When you start deploying your app, you should replace this certificate with a real one: either generated by your internal certificate authority or bought. They will have a longer period of validity, usually a couple of years. You can select any certificate from the dialog in the screenshot above, as long as it has the code signing capability.

Comment: @JitendraJadav And I'm not talking about the developer license validity. Code signing certificate is completely unrelated to it. Of course, you shouldn't unlock your productions machines using the developer license (which is valid for only 1 or 3 months, depending whether the developer has a valid Windows store account). The machines should be unlocked for sideloading either because they are joined to a domain or with a sideloading key.

Comment: @JitendraJadav [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2014/03/24/side-loading-deployment-of-windows-store-apps-in-enterprises-step-by-step.aspx) is a great blog post, both about the certificates and the enabling of sideloading.